# Regex pattern for getting specific string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have links like these:

> http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/21b18be091fe11e39a0512fb41973d49_8.jpg

I want to get everyting after the last "/".
For example, from the link above i would like to get: 21b18be091fe11e39a0512fb41973d49_8.jpg

I cant use SubString because the links could start like: >http://distilleryimage25.s10.amazonaws.com
Than I would have differents lengths.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = "http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/21b18be091fe11e39a0512fb41973d49_8.jpg";
var name = Path.GetFileName(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex.You can do it with using : `LastIndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
var url = "http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/21b18be091fe11e39a0512fb41973d49_8.jpg";
string result = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! All you guys did it!

Answer (score 0):

```
    myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

Obviously I would check if myString.LastIndexOf('/')==-1, before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the regular expression, just use the ["String.LastIndexOf(char c)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int lastIndexOf = url.LastIndexOf('/');
//The zero-based index position of value if that character is found, or -1 if it is not.
string result =  url.Substring( lastIndexOf + 1 );
```